# Meaning of /x|y|z/

Tags: javascript

While going through [this](https://manage.auth0.com/#/applications/gUl64pYcPXvZy02L-U-KPL5CAPvHO3YD/quickstart), I came across the following code:

```js
// src/routes.js

import React from 'react';
import { Route, Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import Home from './Home/Home';
import Callback from './Callback/Callback';
import Auth from './Auth/Auth';
import history from './history';

const auth = new Auth();

const handleAuthentication = (nextState, replace) => {
  if (/access_token|id_token|error/.test(nextState.location.hash)) {
    auth.handleAuthentication();
  }
}

export const makeMainRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Router history={history} component={App}>
      <div>
        <Route path="/" render={(props) => <App auth={auth} {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/home" render={(props) => <Home auth={auth} {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/callback" render={(props) => {
          handleAuthentication(props);
          return <Callback {...props} /> 
        }}/>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

In handleAuthentication, I did not understand what the notation /access_token|id_token|error/ is. Please explain. GitHub link to the code is [this](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-react-samples/blob/master/01-Login/src/routes.js)

Comment: It's a **[Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

The `|` (or) means, that it matches either `access_token`, `id_token`, or `error`:

```js
let re = /access_token|id_token|error/;

console.log(re.test("access_token")) // true
console.log(re.test("something")) // false
console.log(re.test("id_token")) // true
```

Using `.test` on it tests the string passed to it and evaluates if it fits the expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (/access_token|id_token|error/.test(nextState.location.hash)) {
    auth.handleAuthentication();
  }
```

This is just a Regular Expression to test whether the `location.hash` match with `access_token` or `id_token` or `error`.

The `|` in the condition refers to `OR` condition. It executes the `auth.handleAuthentication();` if the `location.hash` match with any one of those three.

Answer (score 0):

It is a regular expression. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

This `/access_token|id_token|error/.test(nextState.location.hash)` means if the value of `nextState.location.hash` is access_token or id_token or error

Answer (score 0):

> There we are checking whether access_token, id_token, or error are present in the authentication hash that comes back from Auth0. If so, we call handleAuthentication.

I found the answer here: https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-react-samples/issues/21